# Adding helper text to options in ValidateSet parameter attribute in Powershell v5

Tags: powershell, parameters, powershell-5.0, validateset

I'm using the `[ValidateSet()]` parameter attribute to validate that the input received by a user is included in the set of approved input values.  However, I was wondering if there was a way of adding helper text to appear in the console when hovering over a given value included in the set.

```
function Get-ObjectAction 
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [parameter(
            ParameterSetName = 'Interactive'
        )]
        [switch]$Interactive,

        [parameter(
            ParameterSetName = 'NonInteractive',
            HelpMessage = "Select the Object to Synchronize: '0 = Users, Contacts and Groups', '1 = Users only', '2 = Contacts Only', '3 = Groups only'"
        )]
        [ValidateNotNullorEmpty()]
        [ValidateSet(0, 1, 2, 3)]
        [int]$Option
    )
}
```

When I run the function in the console, auto-complete displays the available options, though I was wondering if there'd be a way to associate some helper text that would appear next to the autocomplete values for better usability.

Also, when declaring a validate parameter attribute (eg `ValidateSet`, `ValidateNotNullorEmpty`, etc.) the `HelpMessage` specified seems to be skipped, and an exception related to PowerShell's inability to validate the parameter input is thrown instead.  If the first question doesn't have a feasible answer, is there a way to forego the exception related to the parameter validation and prompt the user with the help message instead?

Comment: Are you looking for [comment-based help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help)?

Comment: `HelpMessage` is displayed only if you enter `!?` when PowerShell asks you to supply values for missing Mandatory parameter.

Comment: Thanks beatcracker, that definitely answers the second part of my question.

Comment: Hi Angsar, what I was wondering was if powershell offers a way to present some text when you hover over acceptable parameter values that pop up in the console via intellisense. Thanks.